# MSXML get_documentElement() & returning pointers to COM interfaces

Tags: c++, com, msxml

I was wondering if it is standard practice in COM libraries to call Addref on an COM interface, that is returned from a function. For instance:

```
IXMLDOMElement* domElement = NULL;
document_->get_documentElement(&domElement);  // does get_documentElement() call Addref on domElement?
// ...
// do something with domElement
// ..
domElement.Release(); // correct?
// (btw. member variable document_ is of type CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2>
```

or with a smart pointer:

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> domElement;
document_->get_documentElement(&domElement);
```

Btw. I found that in the docs of MSXML for "Windows media 9 series" it says that Addref is called: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751196(v=vs.85).aspx

But in the official documentation nothing is mentioned about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759095(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are supposed to addref before returning a COM object, as the caller is going to have an new interface pointer referencing the object, so the reference count needs to be increased by one. This is the rule, not the exception.

Documenting the internal addref is the exception, however, as reference counting is one of the fundamentals of COM. Probably the documentation was written when a lot of callers of this method don't know the rule and caused too many memory leaks.

When you, as a caller, no longer need the received object, you need to call Release directly or indirectly (e.g. through a class destructor), and stop using the reference pointer (many people set the pointer to null to prevent dangling pointers).

Answer (score 2):

The function that returns an interface pointer must call `AddRef()` on it before exiting, not the function that is receiving the object. The function that receives the interface pointer must use it as-is and then call `Release()` on it. Which means that `get_documentElement()` will call `AddRef()`, so do not call it yourself.

The rules for who - the caller or the callee - is responsible for doing what in regards to reference counting and memory management in COM are clearly defined in COM's documentation on MSDN:

[The Rules of the Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx)

[Reference Counting Rules](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104138)